# Powershell Get-RsFolderContent pipe to next command

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, export

Trying to script SSRS report export to directory using powershell module called ReportingServicesTool.

Way I see its a two step process:

1. Getting information about Reports that are on SSRS server and using that information
   to create folders with same name.
2. Then exporting all reports that are available in folders on server to local folder on machine.

first step:

```
$rsfolder = Get-RsFolderContent -ReportServerUri 'http://localhost/reportserver' -RsFolder / | select-object name

$dirpath = "D:\ReportExport\" 

##create new report folder based on $rsfolder information## 

foreach ($folder in $rsfolder) 
{
New-Item -itemtype Directory -Path $dirpath -Name $folder
}
```

Second step (to come..)

Situation that I am now in:

Running command Get-RsFolder... on its own lists all Reports (top) name but when I use it further with foreach part it will create folder names that look like this below:

```
@Name=sameofraport
@Name=sameofraport2
@Name=sameofrapor3
```

I remove header info by adding | ft -hide but then piped to foreach it created some random folder names. Clearly command on its own does what I want, but using that info combined with foreach does not give wanted results which is name of folder bases on ones on SSRS server.

Please advise

Comment: Powershell often returns object as the type instead of real type and then it appear that you don't have any results.  I would use $rsfolder | Format-Table to see what actually was returned.  To convert to real type you can use $rsfolder.Foreach([new type]$_)

Comment: Not sure if I understand where are you going with this but here goes:
If I run $rsfolder | Format-Table I get information with out issue, multiple columns
to be exact but I only need information from one called "name" which then will be passed on to foreach. I probably need more explanation about this and hope that you can provide it noob-way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use following : New-Item -itemtype Directory -Path $dirpath -Name $folder.Name  I just added Name to Folder.  Format-Table output gave everything.  So you just need to get the one column.

Comment: I use Format-Table for debugging all the time.  It does a great job of enumerating through Powershell objects.  I often have similar issue as yours that I have table results but cannot get specific objects.  Format-Table tells me that my input data is correct and give me the confidence to isolate the issues.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng that was the thing that I was looking for, being able to choose one column